# Keep protection(or re-protect) certain columns of imported Excel workbook through R

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I have an Excel workbook with two sheets. On the first sheet columns B and C have formulas (referring to the second, still empty, sheet) that are protected against editing. Now I imported this workbook through R, added my data to the second sheet and saved the workbook.

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- loadWorkbook('Tables.xlsx')
writeData(wb, 'Sheet2', mydf)
saveWorkbook(wb, New_tables.xlsx')
```

However, after saving the workbook, columns B and C of sheet 1 are not protected anymore. Is there any specific function that I could add to protect (only) columns B and C from sheet 1 against editing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `protectWorksheet` function you can use.

You will need to `createStyle` to set `locked = TRUE` or `FALSE`then you can control the columns and rows that you want to lock from editing. 
For example:

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "NEW")
writeData(wb, "NEW", mtcars)
addStyle(wb, "NEW", rows = 1:nrow(mtcars), cols = 1, gridExpand = TRUE, style = createStyle(locked = FALSE))
protectWorksheet(wb, "NEW", protect = TRUE)
saveWorkbook(wb, "New_tables.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

This will lock first column up to the rows where data is populated and locks everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't work for me unfortunately. It gives me the following error: Error in createStyle(locked = FALSE) : unused argument (locked = FALSE)

Comment: It sounds like you are using old version of `openxlsx`. try updating packing then you should see `locked` option. `?createStyle` will give you `createStyle(fontName = NULL, fontSize = NULL, fontColour = NULL,
  numFmt = "GENERAL", border = NULL,
  borderColour = getOption("openxlsx.borderColour", "black"),
  borderStyle = getOption("openxlsx.borderStyle", "thin"),
  bgFill = NULL, fgFill = NULL, halign = NULL, valign = NULL,
  textDecoration = NULL, wrapText = FALSE, textRotation = NULL,
  indent = NULL, locked = NULL, hidden = NULL)`

Comment: Got the error fixed. With the commands you're suggesting the whole sheet gets protected, is there also a way to only protect specific columns?

Comment: See above answer - within `addStyle` you will need to specify the columns that you want to unprotect. In the example above it will be column A that you are unprotecting.